# how to get the data from a gambling website using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to get the competition, the name of the teams, the date, the time and the link of each match with this code. I want to get data from this site: `https://www.asianbetsoccer.com/it/nextgame.html`

```
url = "https://www.asianbetsoccer.com/tables/tablenext/cdf8b58456359588508b794fb72d2e16b1e15161.js"

headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.asianbetsoccer.com/nextgame.html",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0",
}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
print(data)
```

I get this answer:

```
var update = "2024-02-05T14:42:15Z"; $("#odds_caption").html("188Bet Odds"); var sf = $("#searchfilter").val();

...
```

but I want to get only the text of every "match1text"

Comment: You will need to use Selenium, Scrapy, or some other tool that renders the JavaScript into the DOM in order to read the data you want, as it is dynamically loaded.  I couldn't find a definitive previous post to mark this as a duplicate of, but there are many posts about scraping dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

`requests` does not bother itself with parsing the responses it gets. If it were HTML, you could use [`bs4`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but since you have JavaScript, I don't see any easier solution than to parse it by hand. Regular expressions will probably help.